# get non duplicate items from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, random, duplicates

Need help! I have a Json file with string values. By clicking on the button, I put a random string from this file into the arraylist. But I shouldn't put duplicate elements in the arraylist. How can i do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Set` instead of a `List`. It does not allow duplicates. You can get more detailed information in the reference documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html.